# If one of the spaces is Hausdorff or regular, or normal, what does that imply about the other?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $X$ and $X'$ denote a single set under two topologies $T$ and $T'$ respectively; assume that $T \subset T'$. If one of the spaces is Hausdorff or regular, or normal, what does that imply about the other?

I have proved that if $T$ is Hausdorff then $T'$ is also Hausdorff.

I'm doing this exercise in Munkres book and got no clue about the solution. Hope someone can help me solve this.

Comment: This really s just an application of the definition of Hausdorff. Hausdorff requires the existence of open sets that satisfy a particular criterion. Adding more open sets doesn't interfere with that criterion.

Comment: Which nomenclature are you using? Does regular mean "$T_3$ and $T_0$", or does $T_3$ mean "regular and $T_0$"?

Comment: @Daniel: Munkres doesn’t use the $T$ terminology, but he does use *regular* and *normal* in what I consider the correct way, i.e., not implying $T_1$.

Answer (score 1):

To complete the Hausdorff part, you need to determine what, if anything, you can say about $X$ if $X'$ is Hausdorff. HINT: If $\mathscr{T}=\{\varnothing,X\}$, then $\mathscr{T}\subseteq\mathscr{T}'$.

For regularity, note that if $\mathscr{T}=\{\varnothing,X\}$, then $X$ is regular. Does $X'$ have to be regular in this case? For a less trivial example, consider the spaces $\Bbb R$ (with the usual topology) and $\Bbb R_K$ in the light of Example $1$ in Section $31$ of Munkres. Going the other way, starting with $X'$ regular and considering whether $X$ must be regular, consider $\Bbb R$ and the finite complement topology (p. $77$) on $\Bbb R$.

The same ideas will handle normality.